# Meaning of $V^0$ in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

According to some notes I am reading, if $A$ is a linear map from $V$ to $V$ then

$$ A^{\mathrm{dim\ V}} = 0 \iff  V ^0= V$$

However I do not know what the notation $V^0$ means. Thank you.

Comment: I suspect it means the generalized eigenspace for eigenvalue $0$ here. This is not a standard notation (it actually conflicts with standard notation).